# sql architect regarding one to many relationship between table

Tags: database-design

I have theoretical question.

I have two tables. as follows:

Table A

```
--------------------------
 id | name | type  | bid |
--------------------------
 1  |  x   | round | 1   |
--------------------------
 2  |  y   | square| 1   |
--------------------------
```

bid is foreign key to table B. Table A to Table B is one to many relationship.

Table B

```
-----------------------------
 id | home_zip | office_zip |
-----------------------------
 1  |  6993    | 6666       |
-----------------------------
 2  |  5867    | 6993       |
-----------------------------
```

I am doing search and finding information on home_zip and office_zip column and dumping into another table C. Table B to table C is many to one relationship

Table C

```
------------------------
 id | zip | information|
------------------------
 1  | 6993| 66668      |
------------------------
 2  | 6666| 98237      |
------------------------
```

My question:

Is it is good to add column b.id in table C, and create duplicated record? or don't include b.id in table C.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add b.id into table C and avoid columns [zip] and [information] at all because you can easily find [zip] and [information] by joining table B via b.id (which is a PK)

Comment: Does not that create duplicated records in system, lets say you have information regrading zip that 6993 which is home_zip for one record and it is office_zip for another record?

Comment: I may not 100% understand you when you say duplicate rows. But if I guess correct, I'd say your table B design is not ideal. It is better that you have three columns for B, [id], [zip], [type], where column [type] will indicate whether the zip value is for office or home (or even other types in future)

Comment: I agree, we are already working on it.  I am asking about table C not table B.